# Animating mouse leave with CSS and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am using CSS transitions to animate a background colour on mouse hover.

I have the following code:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

div:hover {
  background: green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This code only animates the background colour on mouse on. It doesn't reanimate the mouse off. I have 2 questions:

1. How do I animate the mouse off using CSS?
2. How do I do this using **jQuery only**?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/

Comment: 1) http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/1/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1) You change your css to

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    background: red;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
    background: green;

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/2/)

setting the transition to the element, and not the pseudo class.

---

2)

With jQuery you'll either need two elements to cross fade, or a color animation plugin. jQuery UI has color animation built in, and then you can do :

```
$('div').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'green'},1000)
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'red'},1000)
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/3/)

If you're not already using jQuery UI for something else, I'd suggest using one of the much smaller plugins, like [this one](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) !!

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```